# Extract list of file names in a zip archive when `unzip -l`

Tags: linux, unix, ksh

When I do `unzip -l zipfilename`, I see

```
1295627  08-22-11 07:10   A.pdf
473980  08-22-11 07:10   B.pdf
...
```

I only want to see the filenames. I try this

```
unzip -l zipFilename | cut -f4 -d" "
```

but I don't think the delimiter is just `" "`.

Comment: If the number of spaces is fixed, you have to advance the field accordingly, like `-f7` or so. If the *position* of the file name is fixed, use `-b` instead.

Comment: Related on [SU]: [View files in ZIP archive on Linux](http://superuser.com/q/216617/269404)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Assuming none of the files have spaces in names:

```
unzip -l filename.zip | awk '{print $NF}'
```

My unzip output has both a header and footer, so the awk script becomes:

```
unzip -l filename.zip | awk '/-----/ {p = ++p % 2; next} p {print $NF}'
```

---

A version that handles filenames with spaces:

```
unzip -l filename.zip | awk '
    /----/ {p = ++p % 2; next}
    $NF == "Name" {pos = index($0,"Name")}
    p {print substr($0,pos)}
'
```

Comment: Would it be possible if you can explain your `awk` script a bit. totally understand if you dont have time for it.

Comment: Awk has a per-line `NF` variable which is the number of fields. `$NF` is the value of the last field, so that's how you get the filename. The second script works by setting the variable `p` to true when the first line with "-----" appears, and the `{printf $NF}` block only executes if `p` is true.

Comment: You can get rid of the header and footer by using the -qq option: `unzip -l -qq filename.zip`.  Then the simpler awk statement will work.

Answer (score 106):

The easiest way to do this is to use the following command:

```
unzip -Z -1 archive.zip
```

or

```
zipinfo -1 archive.zip
```

This will list only the file names, one on each line.

The two commands are exactly equivalent. The `-Z` option tells unzip to treat the rest of the options as zipinfo options. See the man pages for [unzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) and [zipinfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zipinfo).

Answer (score 6):

If you need to cater for filenames **with** spaces, try:

```
unzip -l zipfilename.zip | awk -v f=4  ' /-----/ {p = ++p % 2; next} p { for (i=f; i<=NF;i++) printf("%s%s", $i,(i==NF) ? "\n" : OFS) }'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use awk:

```
unzip -l zipfilename | awk '{print $4}'
```

Comment: Though, beware of evil filenames that contains spaces.