# Grep inside of multiple directories and zipped files

Tags: regex, grep, gzip

I have a lot of zipped files, where each contains json files and txt files in a directory.
I want to find the total number of json files in all the zipped files in the directory.

To drill it down, I have a lot of such directories.
How do I find out total count of json files within all the zipped files within all directories?

Comment: Something like this might work: find . -name '*.zip' | unzip -l | grep ".json" | wc -l

Comment: Is there a way I can do without unzippig it?

Comment: @user1189851 `unzip -l` prints just the names of the files contained in the archives. And no, you can't do it without unzipping at least that much.

Comment: `zipinfo -1 archive.zip | wc` from a [similar SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7148604/extract-list-of-file-names-in-a-zip-archive-when-unzip-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through the `find` command, you can easily iterate through each directory you have and match against a named pattern such as `*.zip`.

When you go through the list that `find` returns (a `for` loop would be good here) you will need to list the files in each archive (you won't have to extract the files, which is good) and while you're listing the files you can do a simple `grep` to find the `.json` pattern and pipe that output to `wc -l` which will give you a "line count" - in this case it will represent the number of `.json` files.

Throughout the each iteration, you'd take this count and add it to a "total" count which you can then later output.

An expanded sample of this would be:

```
total=0;
for file in `find . -name '*.zip'`; do
    count=`unzip -l $file | grep '.json' | wc -l`;
    total=`expr $total + $count`;
done;
echo "Total Json Files: $total";
```

This sample assumes you're using `zip` to archive your files. If you're using something like `tar` you'll need to use its file-listing parameters (`tar -t`).

Answer (score 1):

zgrep works like grep but handles zip files.  On linux its a shell wrapper, on bsd and osx its a binary.

Comment: This only works on files made with gzip and ncompress (or similar), and not on actual ZIP archives.

Comment: And even worse, zgrep may *seem* to work but in that case it will only grep in one file per zip archive. I got very confused by that while trying to grep in zip archives with multiple files in each.